# How to find the summation of the series :$\sum_{n=1}^{299}\frac{(n+1)^{2}-1}{(n+1)^{2}+1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Q)**Find the value of the summation of the following series:**

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{299}\frac{(n+1)^{2}-1}{(n+1)^{2}+1}$$

Ans) First of all I tried to find the summation of this above series by writing few terms of this series(i.e. by putting the values of $n$).

$S=\frac{3}{5}+\frac{8}{10}+\frac{15}{17}+...+\frac{(300)^{2}-1}{(300)^{2}+1}$

Now I thought of writing the above summation as:

$S=(1-\frac{2}{5})+(1-\frac{2}{10})+(1-\frac{2}{17})+...+(1-\frac{2}{90,001})$

$\implies S = 299-2(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{17}+...+\frac{1}{90,001})$

Now I noticed one important thing here. That is

{$5,10,17,...,90001$} is such a sequence where the sequence of the difference of the terms are in Arithmetic Progression.

That is $10-5=5,17-10=7,26-17=9$ and so on.

Therefore, {$5,7,9,...599$} is in Arithmetic Progression.

But I can't proceed further in finding the summation of this above series. Please help me out.

Comment: Where did this come from? Why do you have reason to believe it has a nice closed-form?

Comment: I think you can show that $300 - \frac{\pi^2}{6} < S <299$

Comment: [The sum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B%28%28n%2B1%29%5E2-1%29%2F%28%28n%2B1%29%5E2%2B1%29%2C%7Bn%2C+1%2C+299%7D%5D) doesn't appear to be anything pleasant.

Comment: @sku, your approximation seems to be incorrect.

Comment: you are right. $S  < 300 - \frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you can write:
$$S = \sum_{n=1}^{299} 1 - \frac{2}{(n+1)^2 +1}$$
$$S = 299 - 2\sum_{n=1}^{299} \frac{1}{(n+1)^2+1}$$

The sum now doesn't really have a nice closed form, so I will approximate it. It can be shown that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{299} \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} = \zeta(2,1) -\zeta(2,301)-1$$ where $\zeta(x)$ is the Hurwitz's Zeta function. The first term is very widely known to be $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ while the second term is a pretty small value (to the order of $10^{-3}$, as verified by a calculator). Then, we can approximate that $$\frac{\pi^2}{6} -1 > \sum_{n=1}^{299} \frac{1}{(n+1)^2+1}$$ which is because $\frac{1}{n} > \frac{1}{n+1}$.

Similarly, we can just do a little manual calculation to show that $$ \sum_{n=1}^{299} \frac{1}{(n+1)^2+1}>0.5$$ which is evident by just considering the first $12$ terms of this sum.

So we conclude that $$299-1>S>299-2\frac{\pi^2}{6}+2 \approx 297.7 > 297$$ which gives us $$298 > S > 297$$ or that $\lfloor S \rfloor = 297$. Also, from $298 > S > 297.7$, we can conclude that $S \approx 298$.

Edit: as suggested by user @CalvinLin, we can use that $\int \frac{1}{x^2+1} dx = \arctan(x)+C$ to bound the sum as well.

Denote by $S' = \sum_{n=1}^{299} f(n)$ where $f(x) = \frac{1}{(x+1)^2+1}$. By considering Riemann sums it becomes clear that

$$f(1)+\int_2^{300} f(x) \le S' \le f(1) + \int_1^{299} f(x)$$ which gives us that $$\tan^{-1}(301)-\tan^{-1}(3)+\frac{1}{5}< S' < \tan^{-1}(300)-\tan^{-1}(2)+\frac{1}{5}$$

But for numerical evaluation the power series $\arctan(x) = x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5} + O(x^7)$ gives us

$0.51 < S' < 0.66$. This gives us that $$297.9 > S > 297.6$$ which is indeed a fairly good approximation.

WolframAlpha shows the sum is about $297.857$.

Comment: Bounding with $ \int 2/[(x+1)^2 + 1 ]\, dx = 2 \tan^{-1} x+1$ seems easier. The largest error arises from the initial terms, which we could account for separately.

Comment: Good idea. I have incorporated the same into my answer.